# Azure DevOps Server 2022 on premises Notifications cannot be disabled

Tags: azure-devops, notifications, on-premises-instances

I had a notification subscription in the project settings to notify me (distinct mail address) for every change of a WorkItem in the project. I got tons of mails then, so I removed the subscription, but it did not help, I still get a mail for every change anybody does in the project at a WorkItem. I checked all possible notification settings from global level (Procect Collection) down to individual, seems all ok (I have admin rights). Even restarted the Azure DevOps Server, but it all did not help, I still get overflowed with Mails.

Comment: Sorry - little mistake. It is the Server 2020, not 2022

Comment: Have you checked the personal notification page? Open User settings, and then select Notification settings from the resulting list. See the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops-2020#view-your-personal-notifications).

Comment: You can also check the [Subscribers section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops-2020#subscribers) with your identity in the Global notifications page in organization setting. You can find all notification subscriptions for you in this view.

Comment: Miao Tian, thanks a lot for the answers. I had already checked all levels of notification settings, as also explained in the links you have set. The only WorkItem - related notifications all over the place are creation, deletion, assignment to a user and mentionning someone by @name. In the meantime I already suspect a bug in the on-premise installation.

Comment: Hi Alexander, if there is a bug in the on-premise installation, you can reinstall the server , there will be a repair option. Or you can update the server to Azure DevOps Server 2022.